# Pointer to array of class functions

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

I'm looking for help here.

my class

```
LevelEditor
```

has functions like this:

```
bool SetSingleMast(Game*, GameArea*, GameArea*, vector<IShip*>*);
bool SetDoubleMast(Game*, GameArea*, GameArea*, vector<IShip*>*);
...
```

In main.cpp I would like to make an array of pointers to LevelEditor object's functions. I'm doing something like this:

```
bool (*CreateShips[2])(Game*, GameArea*, GameArea*, vector<IShip*>*) = 
{LevelEdit->SetSingleMast, LevelEdit->SetDoubleMast, ...};
```

But it gives me an error:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to
'bool (__cdecl *)(Game *,GameArea *,GameArea *,std::vector<_Ty> *)'
with
[
    _Ty=IShip *
]
None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type
```

I don't even know what does it mean. Can somebody help me?

Comment: A pointer to a function is not the same as a pointer to a _member_ function. I recommend you read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Comment: You can't have a pointer to a particular object's function, but to the class' function (method) - `LevelEditor::SetSingleMast`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use ordinary function pointers to point to non-static member functions; you need pointers-to-members instead.

```
bool (LevelEditor::*CreateShips[2])(Game*, GameArea*, GameArea*, vector<IShip*>*) =
{&LevelEditor::SetSingleMast, &LevelEditor::SetDoubleMast};
```

and you need an object or pointer to call them with:

```
(level_editor->*CreateShips[1])(game, area, area, ships);
```

although, assuming you can use C++11 (or Boost), you might find it simpler to use `std::function` to wrap up any kind of callable type:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
std::function<bool(Game*, GameArea*, GameArea*, vector<IShip*>*)> CreateShips[2] = {
    std::bind(&LevelEditor::SetSingleMast, level_editor, _1, _2, _3, _4),
    std::bind(&LevelEditor::SetDoubleMast, level_editor, _1, _2, _3, _4)
};

CreateShips[1](game, area, area, ships);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try this and use typedef also.